# Knockout Maximum Call Stack After Subscribe and AJAX Data Send

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm having a difficult time debugging this infinite loop I've created. In Knockout.js, I've binded a couple elements' change event using the `data-bind="event:{change:save_data}"` markup. Then on the `save_data` function, I have it running an ajax PUT to the server.

```
var ViewModel = function(config) {
    var self = this;

// initial call to mapping to create the object properties
    ko.mapping.fromJS(config, {}, self);

    self.save_data = function() {
    $('#ajax-console').append('<p>Saving...</p>');          
       $.ajax({
          url: '/echo/json/',
          data: ko.toJS(self),
          type:'put',
          success: function(data) {

            },
          dataType: 'json'
        });
    }

};
```

Running this and changing either the input or the checkbox gives me the following error in Chrome: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

What am I doing wrong? Evidently something in the AJAX call is changing one of the field's values. A workaround would be to detect if the AJAX call is already in route and not call it, but I'd like to understand what's going on.

Here are my fiddles:

Broken example:
http://jsfiddle.net/btV9t/10/

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/btV9t/8/

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, when you use the mapping plugin, you need to use it for the `toJS` calls as well, because it creates a viewmodel that is not compatible with the standard `ko.toJS`.

your data line needs to look like this:

```
data: ko.mapping.toJS(self),
```

Here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tyrsius/btV9t/14/)

Comment: Thanks, I changed that in my application. Can't really say this is the _answer_, but it's a good note.

Comment: @StingeyB Is something else still failing? The fiddle is working with that change, so I am not sure what else you are after. How is this not the answer?